# error in in WindowsBase.dll

Tags: wpf, printing

Im having this strange issue.
I need to print some data on fiscal printer (all references are ok).

When I put one single button in my window, and in Click event put that code:

```
        printer eso = new printer;
        string resultString = Regex.Match(port, @"\d+").Value;
        int a = eso._CommunicationInit(int.Parse(resultString), 9600, 5);
        eso._NonFiscalPrintoutBegin(20); 
        eso._pNonFiscalPrintoutLine(20, personNameSurname, 1); 
        // eso._pNonFiscalPrintoutLine(30,Description, 20); 
        eso._pNonFiscalPrintoutLine(40, Math.Round(price, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero).ToString(), 1);
        eso._pNonFiscalPrintoutLine(50, "", 1); 
        eso._pNonFiscalPrintoutLine(70, "", 1); 
        eso._NonFiscalPrintoutEnd();
        eso._CommunicationEnd();
```

But when Im using the same code inside class like:

button.click -> myClass.print(parameters), im getting error

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException'
>   occurred in WindowsBase.dll

Is there any solution for this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe step-by-step debugging to locate the cause of the error easier?

Comment: Well, problem is that both methods print something in fiscal printer. but first method after print does nothing, and second closes application and showing error in VS..

Comment: How is that related to walther's suggestion ?